# Is it possible to spot weld three rather than two plates?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, welding

I have a situation where ideally, I would like to resistance spot weld three rather than the usual two plates together (individual plate thickness approximately 0.7mm). Is this at all possible? If not, why not? Are there any precautions one should take?

Comment: Don't know anything about thicknesses or precautions, so will leave this to someone with more knowledge to write a 'formal answer', but I have seen spot-welds in the real world with at least 4 layers.

Comment: At least that answers the question "Is this at all possible?", so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as per comment, but you have to check current density to make sure sufficient temperature is achieved otherwise the bond between some layers becomes weak.

Making, welding then testing several examples with variations of parameters is usually the way to proceed.